# Observability Inequality from the Carleman's Inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I need to prove the Observability Inequality $$\|\varphi(0)\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C \int\int_{O \times (0, T)} |\varphi^2| \; dx dt$$ from Carleman's Inequality for the heat equation, $- \varphi_t - \Delta \varphi = 0$. Would someone tell me a book or article that has proof of this?

Comment: I guess that your have Neumann boundary condition. There is some good papers which talk about that. See for instance https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0363012904439696  or http://cimpa-icpam.org/archivesecoles/20101130165933/yamamotocarlemansurvey.pdf

Comment: Thank You @Gustave.